# Viewing Geographic information for custom events

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, custom-events

I am using Google's Universal Analytics to track a custom event for a file download.

My question is, how can I view the geographic and language information of the user for this custom event in the Google Analytics reporting website, the same way that I am able to do with geographic information for page views? Is this possible?

If it is not possible to do this with events, can I do it with virtual page views?

My question is more about how to use the GA reporting tool, but here is the code I'm using to send the custom event...

```
ga('send', {
  'hitType': 'event',          // Required.
  'eventCategory': 'files',   // Required.
  'eventAction': 'download',      // Required.
  'eventLabel': fileName,
  'nonInteraction': 1,
  'eventValue': fileID
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible, but you'll have to do this using a [custom report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en).

When you make your custom report, do the following:

- Choose the type "Map Overlay".
- Set the zoom level and dimension to whatever you want.
- Set the metric group to "Total Events".
- Set a filter so the event action is "download" and the event category is "file".

If you want to limit it further to specific files, you can set another filter for event label.